# JQuery Validate - Submit even if required

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have some simple validation:

```
var validator = $("#my_form").validate({
  rules: {
    fieldOne: {
      require_from_group: [1, '.datagroup'],
      email: true,
      maxlength: 40
    },
    fieldTwo: {
      require_from_group: [1, '.datagroup'],
      maxlength: 18,
      minlength: 8
    },
    fieldThree: {
      required: true
    }
  }
});
```

Everything works perfectly.  One thing I am trying to achieve though, is that although fieldThree is required, I still want the form to submit if this has not been provided.  I was hoping the invalidHandler would fire, but it does not seem to.

Is there any way to do a submit even if this field is not provided? (I still want error to display - but I want a silent submit in the background.)

Comment: Remove the `required`.... I can't understand sorry, if you set it as required it means it is REQUIRED.

Comment: Just curious, why do you want to do this? The user will expect that when a field is marked with an error, the form can't be submitted.

Comment: Maybe you could use jquery ajax to send the input field values via post method?

Comment: *"I was hoping the `invalidHandler` would fire, but it does not seem to."* ~ The `invalidHandler` **always** fires upon the button click of an invalid form.  Since you have not shown it to us, we cannot guess what you've done wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to do things that do not follow the API for a library, you have to hack in your own code.  I would write a validator yourself or add to the jQuery validator.

Simply set an event handler to check field 3 on a submission, and remove field 3 from the jQuery validate method.